# How to use microdata with hidden blocks?

Tags: html, seo, microdata

The situation: some div-blocks are hidden with specific display resolution. For example, there are two blocks with a price. One of them is shown above product picture when the display height is small and viсe versa.

Question: how to implement microdata if there are several blocks with identical content but one of them is shown while another one is hidden? Google and Schema.org says  [it is not welcomed](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#schemaorg) to hide marked content.

P. S. The such behavior is realised via css media max-width etc. There's no JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microdata parsers don’t care if the HTML elements are visually hidden; they ignore any CSS.

Specific consumers (like search engines) may decide to handle Microdata from visually hidden HTML elements in a different way, but there are so many consumers (and most of them don’t document their behaviour) that there can’t be a general answer.¹ As many consumers also support JSON-LD, where everything is hidden by default, it would seem inconsistent to handle these two cases differently … but who knows.

So I think you have <s>three</s> four options:

- **Specify the Microdata on the elements for both resolutions (i.e., duplicate it).** But it’s undefined what duplicated properties should mean (in practice this is probably no problem, though).
- **Specify the Microdata only on the elements for one resolution.** Ideally for the variant that most of your users use.
- **Use JSON-LD instead.** But it’s probably not worth to do this only because of that single issue (if it’s an issue at all).
- **Don’t duplicate your content/elements.** ;-)

(I would only mark up the elements for one resolution.)

---

¹ Asking for SEO advice or the behaviour of a search engine service is off-topic on Stack Overflow. SEO-related questions can be asked on [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). See, for example, the questions [Can microdata be implemented in meta tags?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/71555/17633) and [How does Google handle <link> elements in the <body>?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/82788/17633) (Microdata can be specified on `meta` and `link` elements in the `body`; these are hidden by default).